# how to creater a signup register form with my own reqired field form in django?

Tags: django

Im new to django i want create signup form with my own feild ,i dont want to signup form in default that is in user table  i want to created own custom sign up forn any can hepl plz
Im new to django i want create signup form with my own feild ,i dont want to signup form in default that is in user table  i want to created own custom sign up forn any can hepl plz
here is my example how my form feild look like
[enter link description here][1]

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/addyourschool/" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="vhcAZ5w1HpK2mUXMhdqHR1to9Yv2LeOB85E2kR7Z1ZsPo5fjtWZ5P7o23kj8lDsk">

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="form_name">School Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="schoolname" id="product" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Type few letter &amp; select from down *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required." autocomplete="off">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_cfschp">Can't find your School *</label>
                    <input id="form_cfschp" type="text" name="form_cfschpool" class="form-control" placeholder="Can't find your School *" required="required" data-error="Can't find your School">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Pessonname">Contact person Name *</label>
                    <input id="Pessonname" type="text" name="Pessonname" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact person Name *" required="required" data-error="Contact person Name ">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="DesignationatSchool">Designation at School(job title at this section) *</label>
                    <select id="DesignationatSchool" name="DesignationatSchool" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Designation at School">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Request principal">Principal</option>
                        <option value="Request quotation">Founder</option>
                        <option value="Request order status">Management</option>
                        <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Teachers</option>
                        <option value="Other">Others</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password *</label>
                    <input id="pwd" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password *" required="required" data-error="password">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Confirm Password *</label>
                    <input id="pwd" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email *</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tel">Mobile No. *</label>
                    <input id="tel" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Mobile No *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="text-center">  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Register"></div>
                <div class="text-center">Aready Register / have an account ? <a href="/login/">Login here</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

```
username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
subject = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

You have to first create the forms.py file in your app as e.g(contact_us)

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

## Create your views here.

def contact_us(request):

```
#request for POST
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        sender_name = form.cleaned_data['username']
        sender_email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])
        send_mail('New Enquiry', message, sender_email, ['example@gmail.com'])
        return HttpResponse('Thanks for Contacting US')

else:
    form = RegisterForm()

return render(request, 'Contactus/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

After created the forms you have to insert the forms class name in views.py to display the custom form on browser.

```
#Create Your Template
<form id="contactform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="column one-second">
            {{ form.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="column one-second">
            {{form.email }}
        </div>
        <div class="column one">
            {{ form.subject }}
        </div>
        <div class="column one">
            {{ form.message }}
        </div>
        <div class="column one">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>

</form>
```

After this you have to call the form in template. To display your own custom form.
As i did above.